# How does getline() work?

Tags: c++, getline

I have this piece of code that I use to load a linked list from a binary or a text file .. It works fine for text files but it always loads an extra line in the binary case , So I need to know how getline works:

```
while(1)
{
     if(!file.good())
          break;

     getline(file,line);
     student.name=line;

     getline(file,line);
     student.phone=line;

     current->insert(student);
}
```

Comment: "It works fine for text files but it always loads an extra line in the binary case" sorry, wwwhat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it always loads an extra line

Of course: you are inserting what you have read without verifying that it *was* read successfully.

You need to move your `file.good()` test *after* the reading attempt.

Furthermore, there’s no need to test for `good` explicitly, the result of `getline` already gives you the status. The canonical way of loading simple data from a file inside a loop is something as follows:

```
student_type student;
while (getline(file, student.name) and getline(file, student.phone))
    current->insert(student_type(student)); // Makes explicit copy!
```

Comment: @Ahmed Well in that case your text file is including a line ending character that is foreign to the operating system.

Answer (score 2):

getline() reads a \n or EOF terminated line.

So in binary files it doesn't mean much.

> Characters are extracted until either
>   (n - 1) characters have been extracted
>   or the delimiting character is found
>   (which is delim if this parameter is
>   specified, or '\n' otherwise). The
>   extraction also stops if the end of
>   file is reached in the input sequence
>   or if an error occurs during the input
>   operation.

Comment: Agreed. If this is truly a binary file, then finding a newline character doesn't mean anything -- it just means that the encoding used for that type of file produced a 0xD 0xA or 0xA.